# Avoid nested aggregate error using coalesce()

Tags: sql, null, aggregate, amazon-redshift, coalesce

I currently have a query using coalesce that worked in SQL server,however, it is not working in Amazon Redshift. Is there a way I can more appropriately write this to use in Redshift:

```
    coalesce(sum(Score)/nullif(sum(ScorePrem),0),0) as percent
```

Comment: replace `nullif` with `coalesce`.

Comment: What is wrong with the results that you are getting? If you are getting an error, please share the actual error message.

Comment: @zealous it shows that nest aggregate calls are not allowed. I tried replacing nullif, but that also did not help. Any ideas?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name please see the edited post for the query. and here is the version PostgreSQL 8.0.2 and Redshift 1.0.16496

Comment: Well, Redshift isn't Postgres.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the database is postgreSQL

Comment: No it's not - it's Amazon Redshift. Although it shares some ancient roots with Postgres, it is a very different database product. In Postgres you could use the query as-is (assuming you use a valid/legal table name) https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=84374be543cfe73b2daed33bf24c66fc

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I apologize I had thought it was, but that makes sense now. Do you know any work around? I have done research but I am not finding anything great that would work

Comment: See Parfait's answer

Answer (score 1):

Consider running the aggregate query as a subquery or CTE, then handle transformation or secondary calculations in an outer main query.

```
WITH agg AS (
  SELECT calendar_month_id
         ,day_of_month
         ,month_name
         ,DaysRemaining
         ,RPTBRANCH
         ,0 AS TotalGrp
         ,SUM(Score) AS Score
         ,SUM(ScorePrem) AS ScorePrem
  FROM #temp_Score
  GROUP BY calendar_month_id
         , day_of_month
         , month_name
         , DaysRemaining
         , RPTBranch
)

SELECT calendar_month_id
       ,day_of_month
       ,month_name
       ,DaysRemaining
       ,RPTBRANCH
       ,TotalGrp
       ,Score
       ,ScorePrem
       ,COALESCE(Score/NULLIF(ScorePrem,0),0) AS percent
FROM agg
```

Comment: just curious what would that look like with my select together with it? I can't seem to get it working. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Place your original query in CTE, Then select the needed columns with final expression. See edit.